# Impossible to center image, not sure what's going on

Tags: html, css

The header image on this page is impossible to center. I want it in the center of page in its navbar dif but no amount of CSS rules I throw at it can work.

http://couponsite.herokuapp.com/out/1234

I know this really isn't the format for SO but I'm really stuck here and frontend isn't really my world so hopefully someone can help me I assume it's really easy but I can't get it to work

Comment: Remove `width: 100%`  from `.navbar-toggleable-md`

Answer (score 1):

I see you're trying to center it in multiple places using margin: 0 auto;  The reason the styling isnt showing up is that you are applying this styling for a specific media query for mobile devices. If you make the window smaller you can see that the image does get centered.